# Django Locallibrary Project

Tags: django

I am working on locallibrary projects that mostly everybody did and need to add couple feature, but i could not get it. I need to add return book and take a book method/function for users. Inside myborrow list html I add this

```
borrwed_user.html
        <a href="{% url 'book-return' bookinst.book.pk %}">
        <button>Return it</button>
        </a>
```

then add url path

```
path('bookreturn/<int:pk>', views.bookreturn, name='book-return'),
```

then add view

```
def bookreturn(request, pk):
    model = BookInstance.objects.filter(id=pk)
    model.status = 'a'
    return render(request, 'catalog/bookinstance_list_borrowed_user.html')
```

but it does not change status of book or drop the book from borrwer. I am missing something but i did not get it. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects

Answer (score 0):

add model.save() just above return statement to save new status in database

Comment: model.save() gives error however I checked with queryset from python shell and reach to borrower then used this code to drop and worked fine 
def bookreturn(request, pk):
    BookInstance.objects.filter(book_id=pk).update(borrower='')
    BookInstance.objects.filter(book_id=pk).update(status='a')
    return render(request, 'catalog/bookinstance_list_borrowed_user.html')
thank you for your help

Comment: I did't realize it was update view. You've found solution yourself, bravo!